# Chat has the keming all messed up; it's ruining my unproductivity

Tags: bug, chat, fonts

Just look at this keming:

[image]

These are just two small examples. These things are all over the place (consider that 't' is the second most frequent letter in English and 'r' is the ninth most frequent). It's so painful to read.

I'm using Firefox 26, on Windows 7 SP1, at 120 dpi. Firefox's element inspector says the font used is Verdana, with Arial as fallback. If I manually force Arial it suddenly stops looking like the text is trying to kill me.

Comment: I see what you did there.

Comment: FWIW, it looks fine at 96 dpi.

Comment: AAAGH! CHANGE IT BACK!

Comment: Keming is important. http://i.stack.imgur.com/f3lSb.jpg

Comment: Aaaarrrrgggghh. Kerning. It's kerning. It's not keming. Aaarrggghhhh. Pedantry circuits overloaded, humour circuits bypassed, sorry, uuuuufffffffhhhhhh. Nnnnng.

Comment: @someotherguy no, this is clearly keming. Kerning is a different thing, and I wouldn't complain about it.